# Alinhar Icon com conteúdo da LI

Tags: html, css, front-end

> Olá estou começando na área e tentando me especializar em front-end e
> estou tendo dificuldade para replicar o portifólio disponibilizado
> pela rocketseat com finalidade de pratica e estou encontrando
> dificuldade para alinhar o texto com os ícones a esquerda centralizado
> ambos no eixo horizontal e vertical. Espero que possam me ajudar!
> Agradeço desde já!

**CSS**

```css
.social {
  background-color: var(--bg-cards);
  width: 348px;
  height: 292px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.social ul {

  align-items: center;
 
}

.social ul li {
  list-style: none;
  color: var(--text-color);

  text-align: left;
}

.socialIcons {
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.social ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

**HTML**
```

```html
    <div class="social">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img class="socialIcons" src="./style/assets/map-pin.png" alt="País" />Brasil
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="socialIcons"
            src="./style/assets/briefcase.png"
            alt="Trabalho"
          />#
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="socialIcons"
            src="./style/assets/github.png"
            alt="Github"
          />wesleygualberto
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="socialIcons" src="./style/assets/globe.png" alt="Meu Site" /><a
            href="#"
            target="_blank"
            >Meu Site</a
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="socialIcons" src="./style/assets/mail.png" alt="E-mail" /><a
            href="#"
            >Meu E-mail</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

### **Está ficando dessa forma:** [Click aqui para abrir a imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0CSw.png)

### **Modelo que estou tentando replicar:** [Click aqui para abrir a imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqq38.png)

Comment: coloque os textos dentro de um elemento, um `span` por exemplo e vai poder usar propriedades como `position` e `margen` parar alinhar os elementos

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar `display: flex`.

```js
function togleClass(){
  const el = document.querySelectorAll('.elemento-pai');
  for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    let hasClass = el[i].classList.contains("center");
    
    if(hasClass){
      el[i].classList.remove('center');
      }
    else{
      el[i].classList.add('center');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* A mágica do alinhamento centralizado acontece aqui */
.center
{
  display: flex;

  /* Tente comentar uma dela e ver o efeito em funcionamento */
  
  /* Alinha todos os itens filhos centralizados na VERTICAL */
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Alinha todos os itens filhos centralizados na HORIZONTAL */
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}

/* CLASSES VOLTADAS APENAS PARA A EXEMPLIFICAÇÃO, NÃO SÃO NECESSÁRIAS PARA ADAPTAÇÃO */
body
{
  background-color: #22212c;
}

.wrapper
{
  height: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
}

.container
{
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #302f3d;
  padding: 1em 0;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

ul
{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
  
a.elemento-pai
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 1em;
}

a.elemento-pai > span:first-child
{
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

a.elemento-pai:hover
{
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: #393747;
}

.feedback
{
  margin: 1em;
}

.feedback > button
{
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="center elemento-pai">
          <span></span>
          <span>Opção A</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="center elemento-pai">
          <span class="icon"></span>
          <span>Opção B</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="center elemento-pai">
          <span class="icon"></span>
          <span>Opção C</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="feedback">
  <button onclick="togleClass()">Revezar Classe</button>
  <div id="status"></div>
</div>
```

Usando `align-items: center;` no elemento pai dos elementos filhos que você deseja alinhar, ele irá centralizar os filhos verticalmente.

Para centralizar horizontalmente, `use justify-content: center;`